# Define variant type in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, object, mongoose, ocaml, mongoose-schema

I'm familiar with `variant` type of OCaml. For example,

```
type foo =
    | Int of int
    | Pair of int * string
```

I know how to define `Number` and `String` in MongoDB, but my question is how to define the variant type as above in MongoDB:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    num: { type: Number },
    name: { type: String },
    variant: ???
})
```

Does anyone have any idea?

**Edit 1:** I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543379/702977) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548598/702977). They use classes or functions to mimic `variant`. It works well in JavaScript in Front-end. However, the question is whether it is possible to put them in a `Schema`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mongoose wants you to use a nested type to declare a property as an object.  Using your foo type above:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   num: [Number],
   name: [String],
   variant: {
      fooInt: [Number]
      fooPair: {
         fooInt: [Number],
         fooString: [String]
      }
    }
 });
```

Or - you could punt and use `mixed` - but that seems really wishy-washy to me.

Or - in the true spirit of oCaml - you can have that var defined using a pattern (type+object):

```
 ...
 variant: {
    varType: [Number],
    varInfo: [Mixed]
 }
```

Where varInfo's structure depends on varType.  THAT would make your mongo queries eaiser to manage.

Hope that's the direction you were looking for!  FYI - I find [this simple post](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code see the mongo documentation here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    num: { type: Number },
    name: { type: String }, 
    variant: { $type: [ Int: “int” , Pair:[“int”, “string” ] }
```

Comment: Sorry, `$type selects the documents where the value of the field is an instance of the specified BSON type(s)`. `$type` should be used in a query rather than in a schema definition, right?